# Is it ok to make my app's facebook id public?

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, expo

I'm building an app with react native and expo,
and right now I'm working on the login flow. I'll start
with logging in via facebook, and a part of the code in
the tutorials uses my app's facebook id. The thing is, I plan
to make this code public on github, but I'm not sure if the app's
id should be made visible like this. Is it okay to put the id on a
a public repository on github. And if not, what can I do to hide it and
still make the rest of the code public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- App ID: Can be public. If you take a look at the JS SDK examples, they need the App ID client side.
- App Secret: The name tells you that you should keep it secret.
- Access Tokens: Keep them secret.